# Como dar select entre uma hora_minuto e outra no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Preciso resolver um exercício simples pedindo para informar a quantidade de livros vendidos entre as 13h e 17h30 de todas as datas.

Consegui puxar entre as 13h e 17h mas não com os minutos "17h30".

Fiz assim:

```
SELECT SUM(quantidade) 
FROM notafiscal WHERE extract(hour FROM data_compra) BETWEEN 13 AND 17;
```

Tentei usar hour_minute ao invez de hour e por '17:30' mas volta como null qualquer resultado.

Comment: Qual é o tipo da coluna?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente converter em texto:

```
SELECT SUM(quantidade) 
FROM notafiscal 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Data_compra, '%T') BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '17:30:00'
```

Comment: Valeu! funcionou